# I can't ignore a specific file type with createFileSystemWatcher global pattern

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I used vscode API createFileSystemWatcher global pattern to watch for changes in my workspace

```
vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher("**/*.{*}");
```

It works, but I want to ignore watching a specific file extension.

I don't want to watch a ".txt" file extension, so I have tried something like this

```
vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher("**/*.{*, !txt}");
```

it doesn't work. I'm trying not to list out all file extensions in the global pattern, as it may be endless.

Comment: why don't you just check the extension and return immediately if it's one of the ignored ones?

Comment: This was very helpful. I've fixed the issue with your suggestion. Thank you